# How to find if array contains at least one non empty element in ios?

Tags: ios, arrays

I'm attempting to implement the array contains "at lease one not empty object" and my array-list is below.

For this how can we check make condition?

In below array-list I have one non empty object that is "3", so how can we find this using if else conditions?

### my arrayList:

```
arrays list is (
    "",
    "",
    "3",
    "",
    ""
)
```

Comment: Loop through it. If you find a non-empty object, return true. Otherwise return false.

Comment: HOW CAN WE DO IT PLEASE EXPLAIN WITH CODE

Comment: Stack Overflow isn't a code writing service. I just told you how to do what you wish to achieve. The code is almost irrelevant (you haven't even specified a language) - it's the logic behind what you want to do that is important. If you're having a particular problem with how to implement one or more bits of my suggestion, then I would recommend searching SO for how to loop through an array, or how to compare an object - you'll find plenty of resources. And if after that you still are unable to do it, you can come back with some code and a clear problem statement that we can help you with.

Answer (score 0):

```
if ([[yourArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate: [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"length > 0"]] count] > 0) {
    // your array contains at least one "non-empty" element
}
```

explanation: you can use Predicates to filter your original array. In this code, we get a filtered array containing only the  "non-empty" elements, and then we check if the size/count of the array is greater than zero.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing
additional context regarding _why_ and/or _how_ this code
answers the question would significantly improve its
long-term value.  Please [edit] your answer to add some
explanation.

Answer (score 0):

This should work nicely:

```
func hasNonEmptyStrings(stringArray: [String]) -> Bool {
    return !stringArray.filter({!$0.characters.isEmpty}).isEmpty
}
```

This simply filters out any empty strings, and checks if the result is empty.

Answer (score 0):

Swift:

```
if let firstNonEmptyObject = yourArray.first { !$0.isEmpty } {
    //your array contains at least one non empty object
 }
```